# Shared Memory - Sons generate numbers and father sum the results [ UNIX ]

Tags: c, unix, process, shared-memory

I am trying to create a small program that creates two sons ( proccess ), each son generate random number. the father wait for the sons and sum the results.
The Question: What is the modifications I need to do to make it work?

this is what I did so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SEGSIZE 100

void main()
{
    key_t key;
    int   shmid;
    char  *segptr;
    int status=0;
    int r_pid=1;
    int r_pid2=1;
    key = ftok(".", 'T');
    if((shmid = shmget(key, SEGSIZE,IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0666))== -1) 
    {
        printf("Shared memory segment exists - opening as client\n");
        if((shmid = shmget(key, SEGSIZE, 0)) == -1) 
        {
            perror(" bad shmget"); 
            exit(1);             
        }

    }
    else
    {     
        printf("Creating new shared memory segment\n");        
    }
    if((segptr = shmat(shmid, 0, 0)) == NULL)
    {         
            perror("shmat");                
            exit(1);        
    }
    r_pid=fork();
    if(r_pid!=0)
            r_pid2=fork();

    if(r_pid<0 || r_pid2<0 )
    {
            printf("No child created"); 
            exit(1);
    }
    if(r_pid==0  )
    {
            printf("The child process with PID number : %d"" (his parent PID is %d) writes a text to the shared"" memory\n",getpid(),getppid());
            strcpy(segptr,"12");
    }
    else if(r_pid2==0)
    {
        segptr+=2;
        printf("The child process with PID number : %d" " (his parent PID is %d) writes a text to the shared"" memory\n",getpid(),getppid());
        strcat(segptr,"14");
    }
    else
    { 
        r_pid = wait(&status);
        r_pid2 = wait(&status);
        printf(" The following text is received by the ""parent process with PID number pid: %d  pid2 : %d  text: %s\n",r_pid,r_pid2,segptr);


    }

    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0);

}
```

Suggestions Are Welcomed! thanks.
EDIT
Here is some update:
If I initialize segptr with useless chars like: strpy(segptr,"a")
and then in the sons I do strcat(segptr,"test1") and in r_pid2 I do strcat(segptr,"test2")
the father will print test1test2 or vice versa.

Comment: I suggest you take the time to make your code formatted so it is easier to read :-) ... If you have a well formatted source in your IDE (or txt files), paste it all in, then highlight what you have pasted with your mouse, then click the `{}` formatting tool at the top left of the edit box. Good luck.

Comment: You can view the code now, I have copied it from a docx this is the reason it was like that.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the first child runs before the second. So, the

```
        segptr+=2;
        …
        strcat(segptr,"14");
```

may be executed before

```
            strcpy(segptr,"12");
```

causing the first digit of "14" to be overwritten by the terminating null character of "12".

> What is the modifications I need to do to make it work?

Make sure that the writes do not overlap, e. g. by changing the

```
            strcpy(segptr,"12");
```

to

```
        strncpy(segptr, "12", 2);
```